# I have a tram way stations table, I would like to select lines that have common stations

Tags: sql

I have a tramway stations table and I would like to select with SQL query Lines that have common stations.

```
 Ligne |Station
 --------------
   1     |2\n
   1     |3\n
   2     |1\n
   2     |2\n
   3     |4\n
```

The result will be the station 2 because, it's a common station between Lines 1 and 2 : 2.

Answer (score 0):

This query will give back the list of every station on more than one line by grouping by station and then counting the distinct number of lines. The Having clause then filters out any stations that have 1 line.

```
SELECT
    station,
    COUNT(DISTINCT linge) --the count of distinct lines for each station
FROM table

GROUP BY station

HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT linge) > 1 --filters to a list of stations that have more than 1 line
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents here:

```
SELECT Ligne
  FROM stations 
 GROUP BY Station
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

See it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a804/1